# DJango How to select certain item from database table in html

Tags: python, django, object, django-views, jinja2

I have a store page that gets entries from a Products table.
This shows products in order in the same format infinitely for how many are in the table.

`

```
{% for product in products %}
<div class="container2">
  <div href="item" class= 'product-item'>
    <div class= 'image-cont'>
      <a href="item"><img class='product-image'src = '{{product.product_picture.url}}' alt="" ></a>
    </div>
    {% if product.offer != 0 %}
    <div class= 'offer-banner' >
      <a href="item">Special Offer</a>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    </div>
      <div href="item" class="product-content">
        <div href="item" class="product-title">
          <a href="item" >{{product.name}}</a> 
        </div> 
        <div class="product-price">
          <a href="item" >${{product.price}}</a> 
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="product-desc">
          <a href="item" >{{product.desc}}</a> 
        </div> 
        <br>
        <div class="product-userpfp">
          <a href="#" ><img src='{{product.userpfp.url}}'></a> 
        </div> 
        <br>
        <div class="product-poster-name">
          <a href="#" >{{product.username}}</a> 
        </div> 
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

`

I want to be able to click on any product from products and get a page with the specific item I clicked on. This is my Item page.

`

```
{`% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block css %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href= "{% static 'css\item.css' %}" >
{% endblock %}

{%block content%}
{% load static %}

<h1>Item</h1>
<h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
{% endblock %}`
```

`

The problem should be inside the view.py file

`

```
def item(request):
  item = Product.objects.select_related()
  return render(request, "item.html", {"item": item })

def store(request):
  products = Product.objects.all()
  return render(request, 'store.html', {'products': products}) ;
```

`

The store function works. But the item function is not working. My guess is that the 'select_related' may not be the correct tool to use.

I tried changing the select_related tool to a few different ones but was worried I would ruin my table somehow so I am seeking help, Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are passing product_id to the item page when a product is clicked, you need to pass that product_id to the item function and rewrite the code as,

```
def item(request):
  item = Product.objects.select_related('item').get(id=product_id)
  return render(request, "item.html", {"item": item })
```